# No exception/error when no internet coroutine + retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel

I have the following setup

Service

```
// ItunesService
suspend fun searchItunesPodcast(@Query("term") term: String): Response<PodcastResponse>
```

Repository

```
// ItunesRepo
override suspend fun searchByTerm(term: String) = withContext(ioDispatcher) {
    return@withContext itunesService.searchItunesPodcast(term)
}
```

ViewModel

```
fun searchPodcasts(term: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _res.value = Result.loading()
            try {
                val response = itunesRepo.searchByTerm(term)
                if (response.isSuccessful) { // Nothing from here when no internet
                    _res.value = Result.success(response.body())
                } else {
                    _res.value = Result.error(response.errorBody().toString())
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                _res.value = Result.exception(e)
            }
        }
    }
```

Everything works great until i turn off mobile data/internet on my testing device. _res value stuck on Loading state. I have tried adding break point at `if (response.isSuccessful)` when there is no internet and it seams like  `val response = itunesRepo.searchByTerm(term)` never returns how can I fix this

Comment: What network library are you using? By the way your `searchByTerm` function doesn't need to wrap your suspend function call in `withContext()`. It's pointless to try to specify a dispatcher for a suspend function because they are responsible for internally determining whether they need a specific dispatcher.

Comment: are you sure nothing is happening, did you wait long enough? Without network you are bound to get `SocketTimeoutException`

Comment: I am using retrofit @Tenfour04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to using Flow api on my `Repository`

```
override suspend fun searchPodcasts(term: String) = flow {
        emit(Result.Loading)
        try {
            val res = itunesService.searchItunesPodcast(term)
            if (res.isSuccessful)
                emit(Result.Success(res.body()))
            else
                emit(Result.Error("Generic error: ${res.code()}"))
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            emit(Result.Error("Unexpected error", e))
        }
    }.flowOn(ioDispatcher)
```

Then collect the results on my ViewModels